# Error en modelo lineal en R

Tags: r

Estaba realizando un pequeño análisis de unos ficheros que tengo para continuar aprendiendo R y no consigo identificar un error que me aparece cada vez que ejecuto la función de modelo lineal `lm()`.

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = abstencion ~ datos1 + datos2, data = datos,  :  invalid type (list) for variable 'abstencion'

Esto sucede al ejecutar la función `modelo<-lm(abstencion~datos1+datos2, data = datos)`. Es la única función del código que me da error y no me da la respuesta que espero. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradecería mucho, no solo con la respuesta, sino señalándome también cuál es el error para que pueda seguir aprendiendo y que no suceda en un futuro :)

Os dejo aquí el código:

```
    install.packages("readxl");library("readxl")
getwd()
datos1=read_excel("datosOriginales/pruebasjoinConMiExcel.xlsx", sheet=1)
colnames(datos1)
datos2=read_excel("datosOriginales/pruebasjoinConMiExcel.xlsx", sheet=2)
colnames(datos2)

install.packages("dplyr");library("dplyr")
datos1=mutate(datos1, hoja=1) #le añado la columna hoja con el valor 1
datos2=mutate(datos2, hoja=2) #le añado la columna hoja con el valor 2
datos3=merge(x=datos1, y=datos2, by="Municipio") #juntar los dos ficheros en una hoja solo con los valores repetidos en ambos
datos3<-mutate(datos3,Total_población=Total_hombres+Total_mujeres) #añadir nueva columna con la suma de las dos anteriores

indicadores=datos3 %>% group_by(CodComarca.x) %>%
  summarise(media_hombres=mean(Total_hombres),
            desviacion=sd(Total_hombres))
indicadores

abstencion=read_excel("datosOriginales/pruebasjoinConMiExcel.xlsx", sheet=3)
abstencion=mutate(abstencion, hoja=2)
datos<-data.frame(cbind(datos1,datos2,abstencion))
dimnames(datos)



modelo<-lm(abstencion~datos1+datos2, data = datos)
> str(datos)
'data.frame':   112 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ CodComarca   : num  3 2 5 2 3 6 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Municipio    : chr  "Abadiño" "Abanto y Ciérvana-Abanto Zierbena" "Ajangiz" "Alonsotegi" ...
 $ Total_hombres: num  7540 9466 484 2784 18604 ...
 $ hoja         : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ CodComarca.1 : num  3 2 5 2 3 6 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Municipio.1  : chr  "Abadiño" "Abanto y Ciérvana-Abanto Zierbena" "Ajangiz" "Alonsotegi" ...
 $ Total_mujeres: num  7526 9688 454 2930 19114 ...
 $ hoja.1       : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ CodComarca.2 : num  3 2 5 2 3 6 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Municipio.2  : chr  "Abadiño" "Abanto y Ciérvana-Abanto Zierbena" "Ajangiz" "Alonsotegi" ...
 $ Abstención   : num  2643 3574 89 836 5980 ...
 $ hoja.2       : num  23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 ...
```

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo :) y disculpen si es un error tonto, estoy aprendiendo poco a poco el lenguaje por mi cuenta ya que el profesor al que corresponde esta labor únicamente se dedica a exigirnos que copiemos su código sin ni si quiera explicar las funciones, sus utilidades... por lo que si conocéis algún recurso para seguir formándome, agradecería que lo compartiera.

Muchas gracias a todos!

Comment: Bienvenido Unai  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor, agrega a tu pregunta la salida de `str(datos)`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Ya lo he añadido. Supongo que te refieres a eso, no estoy muy entendido al respecto.

Comment: Esta perfecto Unai, lo que estoy viendo es que `data` no tiene las variables que estás usando en el modelo,  `abstencion` pareciera ser `Abstención` y `datos1` y `datos2` directamente no existen

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Patricio, lo he entendido, corregido y el resultado es el esperado :) No había tenido en cuenta que era el data.frame y que en ese caso, tendría que especificar la columna de la siguiente manera: dataframe$columna. Eres de gran ayuda y suerte en lo que te propongas!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido mi comentario. Ya que lo has resuelto, te sugiero que elimines la pregunta, más que nada, por que la respuesta no agregaría mucho contenido útil al sitio. Saludos.